# Parsing XML string using DOM parser returns null

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am trying to get the nested child value from an XML string that is retrieved from DB as a string (cannot modify this step). Whatever I do, the attribute value keeps coming back as null. I need the string value of fbw and bbw tags.

I tried every different combination of `getElementsByTagName`. They all return `null`.

````
String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding = \"UTF-8\" standalone = \"yes\"?><imageresponse><id>123</id><fbw>FWB</fbw><bbw>BBW</bbw></imageresponse>"

DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("imageresponse/fbw");```
````

This is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" standalone = "yes"?>
<imageresponse>
    <id>123</id>
    <fbw>FWB</fbw>
    <bbw>BBW</bbw>
</imageresponse>
```

Comment: If the path does not matter and all you need is the `fbw` element, you can get the correct element by using `getElementsByTagName("fbw")`. Else you will have to use something like [`XPath`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) (see `@omoshiroiii` answer)

Answer (score 0):

I've never personally seen xpath used with getElementsByTagName, but I have seen it used with the xPath class.

```
    XPath xPather = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    String expression = "/imageresponse/fbw";
    NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPather.compile(expression).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

And if you want to get both the fwb and bbw tags:

```
String expression = "/imageresponse/fbw | /imageresponse/bbw";
```